# no puedo ejecutar el proyecto descargado en eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

he descargado un proyecto y al ejecutarlo en eclipse me encuentro que los iconos de los ficheros son un poco diferentes a los iconos de los ficheros de los proyectos mios propios.
alguien puede ayudarme??

agrego una imagen con el icono

he de decir que le cambié el nombre al proyecto para hacerlo más legible para mi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me suena a que no te reconoce el directorio donde están como un "source folder". En todo caso, solo con una descripción es difícil decidir nada ni darte una respuesta, ¿podrías adjuntar un par de capturas de pantalla?

Comment: Tal cual te dicen arriba, fíjate los íconos que son directorios comunes y no packages, y los archivos java no los reconoce como código fuente.
Lamentablemente no sé como ayudarte en Eclipse, pero busca en la configuración de tus proyectos y trata de setear los directorios como source.

Answer (score 0):

Como puse en un comentario, esto es que eclipse no reconoce la carpeta como carpeta de código fuente (por defecto usa $PROJECT_HOME/src)

Opciones:

- Copiar tu estructura de código fuente a /src.
- Ve a la carpeta raíz de tu código fuente, botón derecho -> "Build Path" -> "Use as a source folder".

Nota que la carpeta raíz NO es tu primer package. Si tu package es "es.marcos.loquesea", la carpeta raíz es la que contiene la carpeta "es".

Comment: he cambiado el nombre a las carpetas y me ha vuelto a funcionar. creo que era porque el nombre llevaba  el "punto" .

Comment: muchas gracias a vuestros comentarios